# Differences in Assigning to Temporaries for User-Defined vs Built-in Types in C++

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I have been delving into the intricacies of C++ recently, and there's a specific behavior that has puzzled me: the rules and behaviors around temporaries, especially regarding taking their address and assigning to them.

**Assignment to Temporaries:**
Furthermore, I observed that I can assign to non-const temporaries of UDTs:

```
Rational a(1, 2), b(3, 4), c(5, 6);
(a * b) = c;  // This line compiles
```

However, attempting to assign to the result of a function returning by value (which is an r-value) with built-in types leads to a compile error:

```
int f(int x, int y) {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    f(10, 5) = 12;  // This line won’t compile
}
```

**My Questions:**
Assignment to Temporaries:
How is it possible to assign to a non-const temporary of a UDT?
Is this behavior consistent, and should it be used or avoided in practice?
I've searched through various resources and haven't found a satisfactory explanation for these behaviors. Could someone please shed some light on these issues?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Didn't work for me, I got `error: taking the address of a temporary object of type 'Rational'`.  Perhaps there is a bug in your code that you didn't provided, a [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: Yes. There was a bug! Sorry about that. But still we can assign to user-defined temporary rvalue but it doesn't work for built-in types!

Comment: *But still we can assign to user-defined temporary rvalue but it doesn't work for built-in types!*  For a UDT, you can disallow assignment to a temporary if you want.

Comment: Good point! By doing this ?

friend const Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs ,const Rational& rhs)
 {
  return Rational
  (lhs.m_numerator * rhs.m_denominator, lhs.m_numerator * rhs.m_denominator);

 }

Comment: By doing a member function: `auto operator=(Rational const& b) & -> Rational&;`

Comment: Wow! Interesting! I have never seen this before! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sole reason is that the built-in operators have certain requirements when it comes to the value category of the operand.

> The assignment operator (`=`) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left.
> All require a **modifiable lvalue** as their left operand; [...]

- [[expr.ass] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1)

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be an **lvalue** of some type `T`.

- [[expr.unary.op] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3)

Fr example, `&4` isn't valid because `4` is a prvalue.

Operator overloads can bypass these rules because `&some_rational` simply translates into a function call. If `Rational` has an overloaded `&` operator, you can do `&Rational{}` which would take the address of a prvalue. If `Rational` has an overloaded `=` operator (all class types do, actually), you can do `Rational{} = ...` which assigns to a prvalue. These expression aren't possible for the built-in `&` and `=` operator.

Note that you can disable this behavior using ref-qualifiers:

```cpp
struct Rational {
    /* ... */

    // the & ref-qualifier means that the = operator only works with lvalues
    Rational& operator=(const Rational& other) &;
};
```

Since `const&` can bind to temporary objects, it is not possible to achieve the same for a member function with a `const` qualifier. The closest you could get is using C++23's explicit object parameters:

```cpp
template <std::same_as<const Rational> Self>
address_type operator&(this Self auto& r);
```

Comment: An `operator=` `const`  !? ^_^ and temporary can bind to const ref.

Comment: Thanks for the response so the reason I can do "(a * b) = c;" but can't do " f(10, 5) = 12; " is because as you explained. "you can do Rational{} = ... which assigns to a prvalue. These expression aren't possible for the built-in & and = operator."